# ItamaeにChefの `remote-file` のように外部からファイルを取得する機能はありますか？

Tags: chef, itamae

このようにChefの`remote_file`リソースを使い公開鍵を設置する時にGithub上の物を取得していたのですが、Itamaeの`remote_file`はChefの`cookbook_file`相当という事しかわかりませんでした。
http://qiita.com/fukuiretu/items/170aa956731f2ffb5715#remote_file

```ruby
remote_file "/home/#{user['name']}/.ssh/authorized_keys" do
  owner user['name']
  source "https://github.com/#{user['name']}.keys"
  mode 0600
end
```

Chefの`remote_file`にあたるリソースはItamaeにはないのでしょうか？

無いのであれば作成するユーザー名は決まってるので、ローカルに一度公開鍵を落としてきて作業しようと思っています。

Comment: プロビジョニングってここ(SO)の管轄なのかな…？ itamae公式のslack https://itamae-slackin.herokuapp.com/ で聞いてみたほうがいいかもしれません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Githubに登録してある公開鍵を利用してauthorized_keysを作成するプラグインがあります。
こちらを利用してみてはいかがでしょうか？

https://rubygems.org/gems/itamae-plugin-resource-authorized_keys

Comment: ありがとうございます。できるだけプラグインは使わずに書いていきたいので今回は使いませんがgithubから取得の必要が出てきたら使わせてもらいます。